# Spring boot Redis issues (Kotlin)

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, redis, r2dbc

i am having quite big issues to configure redis to my application. I have this config file:

> @Configuration
> class RedisConfig {

```
@Bean
fun redisConnectionFactory(): JedisConnectionFactory? {
    val config = RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379)
    return JedisConnectionFactory(config)
}

@Bean
fun redisTemplate(redisConnectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory?): RedisTemplate<String, Any> {
    val template = RedisTemplate<String, Any>()
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory!!)
    return template
}
```

}

the gradle file looks like this:

```
 implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:3.0.2")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3")
    implementation("com.mailjet:mailjet-client:5.2.2")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis"
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
```

Error happens the moment I add the data-redis dependency:

```
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis")
```

The actual message of error is:

> Parameter 5 of constructor in
> com.skenarios.microservices.export.services.DataService required a
> bean of type
> 'com.skenarios.microservices.export.repository.MyRepo'
> that could not be found.

Repository looks like this:

> interface RenovationRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<TypeYearValue, Int> {

```
@Query(
    """Here my query"""
)
fun findItemsById(buildingId: Int, start: LocalDateTime, end: LocalDateTime): Flow<TypeYearValue>
```

I feel like redis somehow conflicts with r2dbc dependency. Atleast from the searches I made that's what people saying. All my entities got also annotation @Table (which was suggested in some places as a fix).